# dual vs single rail speaker excrusion

Tags: power-supply, dual

Is there a difference in speaker total excrusion if i using single and dual? Like if single it's just excrused from 0mm to like says, 5mm. and if it was  dual rail i'll go from -5mm to 5mm? If yes then the single rail is actually less useful somehow? (Because inability to reach -5mm, so the power handling are divided by 2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you feed only half the peak-to-peak voltage to a speaker, it will move only half the distance.

However, 1/2 the voltage gives you (1/2)<sup>2</sup> = 1/4 the power.